# Running Kafka Connect with Avro Converter : ConfigException: "Missing Schema registry url"

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-connect

Hi Im running Kafka Connect docker images

```
docker run -d \
  --name=kafka-connect \
  --net=host \
  -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=localhost:39092 \
  -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=28082 \
  -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="quickstart" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-config" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-offsets" \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-status" \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL="http://localhost:8081" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL="http://localhost:8081" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="localhost" \
  -e CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT="localhost:2181" \
  tim/kafka-connect
```

and getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing Schema registry url!
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.configure(AvroConverter.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.<init>(Worker.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:74)
```

can't figure where to add "schema.registry.url" conf !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem was with the `_INTERNAL_KEY_` and `_INTERNAL_VALUE_`
I wasn't adding the SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL for these two the same way I did for `_KEY_CONVERTER` and `_KEY_VALUE` any way I switched back to `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` for the internal key and value

Comment: This is the correct answer. The avro converter used here requires a schema registry URL configuration for each instance that it is used in. The JsonConverter has no such requirement although it has its own  specific configuration options if you want to use them (e.g. schemas.enable).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `.properties` file, you will need:

```
:internal.key.converter.schema.registry.url http://urlgoes.here
:internal.value.converter.schema.registry.url http://urlgoes.here
```

If you're passing in command-line environment variables, you will need:

```
INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://urlgoes.here
INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://urlgoes.here
```